# Command line tool to mimic Xcode's "Fix Issue" creation of .mobileprovision

Tags: xcode, xcode7, ios-provisioning

As of Xcode 7, you can sideload your apps onto your device.  When you create a project, and first want to sign it, you can click the 'Fix Issue' button which will generate a .mobileprovision for the selected device and developer account.

I'm wondering how Xcode does this, or if there exists an Xcode command line tool that mimics this process of generating a .mobileprovision without a paid developer account, that will work on a specific device and developer account.

<del>If there happens to be a command line tool that's not Xcode, that could also be useful.</del> It was pointed out that I shouldn't ask for off-site tools.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow. That being said, [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) could be of some help.

Comment: Why is this off-topic for StackOverflow?  What would be the right place for this question?  While I probably phrased the question badly, the main question was how Xcode accomplishes this.

Comment: ["Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's probably open to interpretation, we'll see if the question gets closed ;)